# How to access provider values in integration test with Consumer?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am using provider package and I moved my whole logic of class to provider.

I used Consumer:

```
Consumer3<NewLocationProvider, ListProvider, NewFilterProvider>(
            builder: (context, newLocationProvider, listProvider,newFilterProvider, child) {
                   // class code
            }
```

and everything working fine, but when I want to test functionalites from this class in integration testing I can't access values from these providers.

Here is what I did in my integration test:

```
class MockBuildContext extends Mock implements BuildContext {}

late MockBuildContext _mockContext;


 setUp(() async {
   _mockContext = MockBuildContext();
 });
```

```
await tester.pumpWidget(
          LocalizationsInjector(
            child: MultiProvider(
              providers: [
                ChangeNotifierProvider<NewFilterProvider>(
                    create: (_) => NewFilterProvider())
              ],
                child: MainNavigator()
            ),
          )
      );
```

and when I call provider this way:

```
      print(Provider.of<NewFilterProvider>(_mockContext, listen: false).selectedTagsWithCategories);
```

I am getting null and this error:

```
The following _CastError was thrown running a test:
Null check operator used on a null value
```

So my question is how to access this values with this approach in class code?

Comment: Please migrate to Riverpod as Provider is very likely to be depreciated soon. Riverpod is the remake of the provider package, however it fixes issues like this. See the [docs](https://riverpod.dev) of riverpod.

When you have migrated, see [this](https://riverpod.dev/docs/cookbooks/testing). Its the tutorial for testing providers in Riverpod.